# When creating an event from 12:00am to 12:30am it shows up as all day event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

However if I change the time to 12:00am to 1:00am, it renders in the time slot and not as an all day event?  Not sure whats going on!

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query = "select id,class_name,bridge,start_time,end_time from $table";
$results= mysql_query($query,$conn);
$total = mysql_num_rows($results);

if ($total > 0) {
    // Start a JSON object called "property" which will be an array of resort properties from around the globe.
    echo "[" ;

    $counter = 0;
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {

        list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $item->start_time);
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $s_timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

        list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $item->end_time);
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
        list($hour1, $minute1, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $e_timestamp = mktime($hour1, $minute1, $second, $month, $day, $year);

        #if ( $hour > 0 ) {
        #$a_day = 'false';
        #} else {
        #$a_day = 'true';
        #  }

        if ( $hour == 0 && $hour1 == 0 && $minute == 0 && $minute1 == 0 ){
        $a_day = 'true';
        } else {
        $a_day = 'false';
          }


        echo "{'id':$item->id, 'className':'$item->class_name', 'title':'$item->bridge', 'start':'$s_timestamp', 'end':'$e_timestamp', 'allDay':$a_day}";

        $counter++;

        if ($counter < $total) { echo ", "; }
    }

    echo "]";
  }
```

Comment: Please add more details - and code

Comment: Thanks Mike, when I went to post my code I notice the bug causing the problem. The issue was in my json.php.... sorry to waste the boards time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike, when I went to post my code I notice the bug causing the problem. The issue was in my json.php.... sorry to waste the boards time.

I needed to change the way I was looking at my hours and minutes when setting the allday tag.  You can see where I commented out the bad code.

Comment: You could still update your question with more details and the buggy code and then edit your answer here with the actual answer.  This would help anyone who ran into the same issue.